# OG meta data issue using Feed dialog

Tags: dialog, metadata, facebook-opengraph, fb.ui, og-meta

When sharing a website via FB.ui (feed dialog) and it hasn't been scraped yet by the Facebook Debugger the preview in the feed dialog looks fine, but when the link is shared it is shared as a complete URL (all og meta data seems to be lost).

It also breaks when the feed dialog is called for the second time.

Reproducable on this link:
https://devmonks.vellance.net/fbui.php

- Click on post.
- Click cancel in the popup.
- Click again on post (with the same random parameter in the textfield).

Expected Behavior:

- Click on post -> you see the og meta data in the popup.
- Click cancel in the popup.
- Click again on post (with the same random parameter in the textfield) -> you see the og meta data in the popup.

Actual Behavior:

- Click on post -> you see the og meta data in the popup.
- Click cancel in the popup
- Click again on post (with the same random parameter in the textfield) -> you don't see the og meta data in the popup.

Is this a bug in Facebook?

Comment: i have the exact same problem :( were you able to fix this?